# how to make a picture spin when the cursur is hovering above it

Tags: html, css

I was making a webpage and I want to make an image rotate when the mouse hovers above it. My code is this:

```
img:hover {
    border-color: navy;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
}
img {
    border: 2px solid White;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
            transition:         transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

It works fine but the only problem is that it turns back when I remove my cursur. How could I prevent that?

Comment: Please use the embed HTML/CSS/JS code function to provide us a runable code example. Therefore we can help you much easier.

Comment: how do i do that?

Answer (score 4):

You have to adjust the `transition`.

Make it `0s` for the regular transition, and `1.5s` when you hover the img.

```css
img:hover {
    border-color: navy;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
            transition:         transform 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
img {
    border: 2px solid White;
    transition: 0s;

}
```

```html
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200"/>
```

Comment: it seems to work bu the problem is when you remove your cursur, it just flips back to the normal position. can you make it rotate back if it doesn't turn all the way?

Comment: @MagicKidkid this is what your initial code is doing

Comment: what im trying to say is that i want it to be so that if the mouse is removed, it flips back to the normal position. otherwise,  it keeps going until it reaches the 360 move.

Comment: @MagicKidkid, You mean that you want the image to never rotate again if it has completed a full rotation? It's not clear what you're asking for, sorry.

Comment: @MagicKidkid yes, your code is doing exactly that

Comment: talking to amaury

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Amaury's answer, you can also use css's [animation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) property.

```css
img {
    border: 2px solid White;
}

img:hover {
    border-color: navy;
    animation: rotate 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/200x200"/>
```